# unwanted multiple ajax request to an action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript

I am developing an asp.net mvc application and have ajax calls on my page. Here is a form which I load by ajax call to page :

The form is located in a partial view

```
<div id="CreateCultureArea">
 <% 
        using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateCulture", "Admin", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "handleCreateCulture" }))
        { %>
.....

<% } %>
</div>
```

**Code Updated**

The following script is located in a view :

```
<a href="#" class="CreateCulture" id="">Create Culture</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.CreateCulture').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var idval = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/CreateCulture",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { id: idval },
                success: function (mydata) {

                    $("#CultureContentArea").empty();
                    $("#CultureContentArea").empty().hide().append(mydata).fadeIn(2000);

                    $("form").removeData("validator");
                    $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");

                },
                type: "GET"
            });
            return false;
        })
    </script>
```

When users click on a link with CreateCulture class, the form is loaded to page. But as I saw the requests in firebug, it calls the action multiple times. I read similar posts like mine on stackoverflow.com and most of them suggested removing repetitive "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" calss in page, but as I saw the output page I only see on link to the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" script.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `@Ajax.BeginForm` emits a form that has the attribute `data-ajax="true"`.  In the unobtrusive AJAX script (see the non-minified version and look for calls to `asyncRequest`).  So by calling `$.ajax` yourself, you are repeating the work of `@Ajax.BeginForm`.  Just take out your call to `$.ajax` and you'll see your action get called only once.

If you need to take action after the AJAX call completes, set the `OnComplete` property of `AjaxOptions` in your call to `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: sorry but I cant understand " Just take out your call to $.ajax and you'll see your action get called only once", would you please tell more ?

Comment: In the example code you posted, you have a call to `$.ajax` in your click handler for `.CreateCulture`.  It's being called once by unobtrusive AJAX, and then again by your code.  Remove the call to `$.ajax` from your code.  As a matter of fact, you can remove everything in the `<script>` tag you have listed above.

Comment: If you need to take action after the AJAX call is completed, set the `OnComplete` property of `AjaxOptions`.

Comment: I edited the code. The fact is that ajax form is in a partial view and link with CreateCulture class is in other view. When user click on link, the partial view loaded to other view.

Comment: I dont have any problem taking action after the ajax call being completed. I can show the user appropriate message. Code Updated

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have not multiple .js refrence in page

```
<script src='/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js'></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I put some scripts in partial view and each time it duplicated by loading this. So I put the scripts all in on page and problem solved.